# How to change data-source path "local:/data/test" to GUID programatically when saving page in Experience editor

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, datasource

We are using `Sitecore 9 with SXA`. As per my understanding, it was designed to have a path with `local:/` for certain reasons. But, as per our business requirements, we need to update rendering with a data-source id as the authors requires to change the data-source item names frequently. So, Is there any way that we can update the data-source path `(local:/data/item)` with item-id while saving the page in experience-editor?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The below link exactly answers your requirement -

> https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/convert-data-source-paths-to-ids-using-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Its a little old post but the fundamental idea driving the programming logic for your requirement can be driven from here.

Comment: Link-only answers _will_ be removed.